# click() is not working for input tag in selenium using nodejs

Tags: node.js, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver, webautomation

This is the element that I am trying to click. I am not getting any error but the click is not working.

```
<input class="btn-add-cart button js-form-submit form-submit" data-drupal-selector="edit-add" type="submit" id="edit-add" name="op" value="Add to Cart">
```

I tried using XPath, className, id, and CSS selector. Here is the code of how I tried using CSS.

```
  let path = `#edit-add`
  await driver.wait(until.elementLocated(By.css(`${path}`)),1000);
  const element = await driver.findElement(By.css(`${path}`))
  await driver.executeScript("arguments[0].click();", element );
```

[Here](https://oneprovider.com/order/item/dediconf/2710) is the webpage I am trying to automate.

And I am trying to click on Add to Cart button at the bottom of the page.

[image: Add to Cart button]

I also tried by scrolling page to button but it is also not working. I think click is not applicable to this input element. Correct me if I am wrong. Please suggest a way to click on this button.

Thank you!

Comment: maybe try:
`JavascriptExecutor executor = (JavascriptExecutor)driver;
executor.executeScript("arguments[0].click();", element);`

Comment: Can we use JavascriptExecutor in nodejs? How to import it? I think it also same as driver.executeScript("arguments[0].click();", element );

Comment: Have you also tried simply: `driver.findElement(By.css(``${path}``)).click();`

Comment: That gives an error.

Answer (score 0):

Can you try the xpath as

```
driver.FindElement("//input[@value = 'Add to Cart' and @id='edit-add']"); 
((JavascriptExecutor) driver).executeScript( "arguments[0].scrollIntoView();", element); 
Actions act = new Actions(driver); 
act.moveToElement(element).perform(); 
Thread.Sleep(2000); 
((JavascriptExecutor) driver).executeScript( "arguments[0].Click();", element);
```

Comment: Tried but still not working. Xpath and other referring methods to element are working correctly. 
But Click() is not working. 

I am wondering what is the issue. If I am able to click on UI, Why it is not clicking in automation.

Comment: Have you checked whether button is present in frame or not. If button is present inside frame you need to switch to frame.

Comment: What do you mean by frame? The button is locates at the bottom of the page so I used scrollIntoView() to scroll the page before running click()

 await driver.executeScript("arguments[0].scrollIntoView();", scroll );

The page is scrolling but still not clicking.

Comment: I have updated my answer, try that. Are you using Selenium or Protractor and which language are you using?